# Redirect after login by User Role PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've browsed multiple articles on stack but I've had no luck with this so I thought I would ask.
I have a Mysql Database

```
username | password | userType
someguy1 | 1234567  | R
coolguy1 | @1234    | A
```

I would like both of these users to be able to login in the same area, but I would like the R user type to be redirected to a page like /index.php while anyone with A will be redirected to a/index.php

Comment: so, what is the problem ?

Comment: when you check email and password that time if it is correct than check role and redirect on respective page. Also check this role on those page also

Comment: I'm looking for the code on how to do this, This is something I've never accomplished and I don't know how to form the redirect on login

Comment: upon getting the result set from your query, get the `userType` column and then redirect to your desired location

Comment: Have you created a login page yet?

Answer (score 0):

structure your project like this (just for example):

```
project
 -index.php //where R type user will be navigated
 -aindex.php //where A user type will be navigated
 -login.php //this is where the login form is, set your form action="login_logic.php"
 -login_logic.php //this is where the form submits login details and check the user type
```

In your login_logic.php :

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

sql = SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'; //I am skipping this as you seem to know how to query ...smthing like that
//then check for password and verify user and get the usertype



//after getting the usertype check the type then simply re-direct
if(user['userType'] == "R"){
 header("Location:index.php");
 } elseif(user['usertype'] =="A"){
 header("Location:a/index.php");
}

}
```